# Itext sign pdf by string signature in base 64 from client

Tags: java, pdf, itext, sign

I am trying to sign a pdf document with a signature that comes from the entire client in format base 64.

1. the service makes a request to calculate the hash from the document
2. I take the content from the pdf of the document, calculate the hash from it according to the algorithm.
3. service takes the received hash and signs it, sends the received signature along with the bytes of the document to be signed
4. I get a string in base 64 and pdf bytes to be signed

Is it possiple case? I give a code example

```
public byte[] insertSignature(byte[] document, String signature) {
    try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(document);
         ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        byte[] decodeSignature = Base64.decodeBase64(signature);
        CAdESSignature cades = new CAdESSignature(decodeSignature, null, null);
        var certificate = cades.getCAdESSignerInfo(0).getSignerCertificate();
        var subject = new Subject(certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getEncoded());
        List<String> names = getSignaturesFields(document);
        String sigFieldName = String.format("Signature %s", names.size() + 1);
        PdfName filter = PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite;
        PdfName subFilter = PdfName.ETSI_CAdES_DETACHED;
        int estimatedSize = 8192;

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
        StampingProperties stampingProperties = new StampingProperties();
        if (names.size() > 1) {
            stampingProperties.useAppendMode();
        }
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, stampingProperties);
        signer.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance
                .setContact(subject.email().orElse(""))
                .setSignatureCreator(subject.organizationName().orElse(""))
                .setLocation(subject.country())
                .setReuseAppearance(false)
                .setPageNumber(1);

        signer.setFieldName(sigFieldName);
        ContainerForPrepareSignedDocument external = new ContainerForPrepareSignedDocument(filter, subFilter);
        signer.signExternalContainer(external, estimatedSize);
        byte[] preSignedBytes = os.toByteArray();

        ContainerReadyToSignedDocument extSigContainer = new ContainerReadyToSignedDocument(decodeSignature);
        PdfDocument docToSign = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(preSignedBytes)));
        PdfSigner.signDeferred(docToSign, sigFieldName, result, extSigContainer);
        docToSign.close();
        return result.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new InternalException("IO exception by insert signature to document:", e);
    }
    catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new InternalException("General security by insert signature to document:", e);
    }
    catch (CAdESException e) {
        throw new InternalException("CAdESException by insert signature to document:", e);
    }
}

private List<String> getSignaturesFields(byte[] document)
        throws IOException {
    try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(document);
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
         PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader)) {
        SignatureUtil signUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
        return signUtil.getSignatureNames();
    }
}

static class ContainerForPrepareSignedDocument implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
    private final PdfName filter;
    private final PdfName subFilter;

    public ContainerForPrepareSignedDocument(PdfName filter,
                                             PdfName subFilter) {
        this.filter = filter;
        this.subFilter = subFilter;
    }

    public byte[] sign(InputStream docBytes) {
        return new byte[0];
    }

    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        signDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
        signDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
    }
}


static class ContainerReadyToSignedDocument implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
    private byte[] cmsSignatureContents;

    public ContainerReadyToSignedDocument(byte[] cmsSignatureContents) {
        this.cmsSignatureContents = cmsSignatureContents;
    }


    public byte[] sign(InputStream docBytes) {
        return cmsSignatureContents;
    }

    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I take the content from the pdf of the document, calculate the hash from it"* - Do you hash the original PDF? Or have you already prepared it for signing? Signing PDFs requires you to first prepare the original PDF by setting a value to a previously existing or a new PDF AcroForm signature field; this value includes a placeholder into which later the signature container is to be embedded. For details read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096). Of this prepared PDF you have to hash everything *except* the placeholder.

Comment: you mean that in any case, you will need to create a container in the file for the signature and take the hash from the byte array, like this example : https://github.com/ink-elements/itext7-js/blob/fe5ebd54c0e040de22c66ac06864c222e0387b24/itext7/sign/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/signatures/sign/SignDeferredTest.java  test calcHashOnDocCreationThenDeferredSignTest01

Comment: Strictly speaking that is not an example but those are a number of unit tests which test certain aspects of deferred signing, but yes, you have to prepare the PDF similarly to how it's shown in some of the tests there before starting the hashing.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in this case each time hash will be different. For example, we take one file, add a container for signature there and calculate the hash from /ByteRange, 
As a result, I get hash 1, if I do the same the second time, then there will be a different hash even with the same algorithm?

Comment: Usually yes because there are entries like creation/modification time, signing time, and unique document IDs involved. You can of course try and patch iText to use values you can prescribe.